# Appropriate way to bring web.config changes into force

Tags: asp.net, web-config

what is the suggested way to make web app see new configuration in web.config ?

- restart IIS
- stop/start app pool
- recycle app pool
- custom web page that does something in code?

Thanks,Pawel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to do anything: when the web.config file is modified, ASP.NET will automatically recycle the AppDomain and the application will reload the file.